# How to trigger a function after elements get rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I want to access an element using React.createRef() (which is inside a function). Below is the example of how I want to access it.

**react:**

```
someFunction = () => {
   let element = this.myRef.current;
   console.log(element)
}
```

```
render(){
  return(
     <FlexView>
        <div ref={this.myRef}>
          some text here 
        </div>
        {this.someFunction()}
     </FlexView>
  )
}
```

Here, I want to access the div element through **someFunction()**. But for some reason **this.myRef.current** is returning a null value in console - I guess the issue is related to react life cycle, but I just can't figure out why. However by using the button, I can able to access the div element without having any problem, but only when I try to use the above method to trigger a function it's returning null.

```
render(){
  return(
     <FlexView>
        <div ref={this.myRef}>
          some text here 
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.someFunction()}>click-here</button>
     </FlexView>
  )
}
```

Can someone please let me know how do it.

p.s. I'm new to React and Js

Comment: You need to call the function inside `componentDidMount` to get the data after comonent rendered like `componentDidMount() {
    this.someFunction();
  }` . Working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-createref-forked-kwdbgd

Comment: I guess what you want here is an componentDidMount  ... my bad thought a function component - [A great visual reference here](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)

Comment: Thanks a ton @ManirajMurugan **componentDidMount** worked.

Comment: Thanks for the visual reference you've shared @KcH. It'll be of great help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  class Component extends React.Component{
      constructor(...args){
        super(args);
        this.ref = React.createRef();
      }
      state = {
        isLoaded = false;
      }
      componentDidMount(){
          this.setState({isLoaded:true})     
        }
      someFunction = () => {
         let element = this.myRef.current;
         console.log(element)
      }
      render(){
        <FlexView>
          <div ref={this.ref}>
            some text here 
          </div>
          <button onClick={this.someFunction}>click-here</button>
       </FlexView>
      }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in the first case the function is expected to return some html i.e div and since the function does not return anything it returns null and nothing is executed inside the render.

Comment: Yeah! But in both the cases, function get's executed. While in the first case, it's printing the proper div on console. But in the second case it's returning null as it doesn't able to read the element properly.

Comment: yes  you are right . This is strange why it doesnt work here .

Comment: Hmm yeahhh! However, componentDidMount worked for me in this. It works now. Thanks you so much @Tarmah

Comment: great to know :-)